# Range and loops

Tags: python, while-loop, range

Looking for a way to explain something in Python to my students. If we start with number_list = range(100), we can use a for loop such as...

```
for n in number_list: (do something)
```

If we have the same set up, but try to use a while loop, n comes back as undefined. How do I explain that?

```
while n in number_list < 20: (do something)  --> n is undefined
```

I guess it is more curious why it's OK in the for loop. I have been harping on them to initialize variables before using them, so why does n work just fine in the for loop?

Comment: I am (happily!) surprised that you received your answer here, where "how to explain" is typically not on-topic, but just so you know, questions like this would typically fare better in [cseducators.se], a whole community of educators created specifically for this sort of thing. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `in` in a `for` loop has a different connotation from the `in` used in a `while` loop.

The `for` loop's syntax is defined in the [grammar file](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/grammar.html#full-grammar-specification) for the language, particularly, this line:

```
for_stmt: 'for' exprlist 'in' testlist ':' suite ['else' ':' suite]
```

Which indicates that `in` is part of the *syntax* that defines a `for` loop.

In the case of a `while` loop, which is a *condition controlled* loop. Anything that comes after `while` is treated as an expression that is to be evaluated and its truthiness tested.

So, the `<something>` in `while <something>:` is an expression. In your case, it is `n in number_list < 20`. In this case, the `in` has a different connotation, it is an *operator* that is used to test inclusion.

```
In [173]: n = 4

In [174]: n in range(1, 10)
Out[174]: True
```

In your particular case, `n` is not defined at the time the expression is evaluated, and so a `NameError` is raised.

---

I understand that this might be too complicated an answer to throw at students who have next to no experience with python.

I would touch upon the fact that the `in` in `for ... in ...` is an artefact of the syntax for a `for` loop, and the `in` in the `while <something>` statement is an operator, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful way to explain.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `while` loop is mostly gibberish. There's no `in` clause in a `while` statement (unless you're using the `in` operator to check if a value is a member of a container). Unlike a for loop, a `while` doesn't assign any value to a name on each iteration, it just checks the truth value of the expression you give it. That expression needs to be valid *before* the loop runs!

You can write a `while` loop that is almost equivalent to your `for` loop:

```
number_list = range(100)

iterator = iter(number_list)
try:
    while True:
        n = next(iterator)

        # do stuff here with n (body of the loop)

except StopIteration:
    pass
```

(The only way this is different from the for loop is that it creates the name `iterator` in the current namespace, while a `for` loop stores its iterator internally, without it being accessible to Python code.)

Unfortunately, that loop is unlikely to be easier for your students to understand, since exceptions are probably more complicated than looping.

If you only need to be able to iterate over a sequence (such as a `list` or a `range`), you can make a simpler `while` loop that uses an index to get each value from the sequence, rather than using the iterator protocol:

```
number_list = range(100)

i = 0
while i < len(number_list):
    n = number_list[i]

    # do stuff with n here
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for n in number_list: (do something)
```

Pick one element from the number_list(in Pur case its a range) then save that value in a variable called 'n' , the value of the 'n' will change every time you run the for loop. the loop will exit when it encounters a 'StopIteration'. The variable 'n' will get created automatically with a value we fetch from the number_list

> `while n in number_list < 20:`

Here you checking a variable's value present inside the list number_list. But it is not defined. while only runs when it get True value from the condition

Answer (score 0):

Although the `for` type-statement-construct appears in many programming languages, its meaning in Python comes alive due to the ability to iterate over the contents of container objects. But here is a really simple 'for loop' constructed in Python using the 'while` statement.

```
n = 0
while n < 100:
    print (n)
    n = n + 1
```